# Maven assembly plugin doesn't compress (deflate)

Tags: android, maven

I'm trying to generate a .zip artifact with maven-assembly-plugin for an Android project. How can I set up the maven assembly plugin to use deflate compression?

Longer explanation question:
That artifact should contain only the .apk, which was generated by the android maven plugin (yes, I know the .apk is practically a .zip file itself, but our automation team needs this apk packed in a zip format).

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>package.MessageReceiver</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>assembly_zip.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <archiverConfig>
                    <compress>true</compress>
                </archiverConfig>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Assembly config:

```
  <assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
            <id>automation</id>
            <formats>
                <format>zip</format>
            </formats>
            <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
            <files>
                <file>
                    <source>target/${project.build.finalName}.apk</source>
                    <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
                    <filtered>false</filtered>
                </file>
            </files>
        </assembly>
```

- the .apk is generated
- the .zip file is created
- the .zip file contains the .apk

What is not working is the packing. It turned out, when the plugin creates the zip file, it only puts the files in the zip container, but does not use any compression. On mac the standard "unzip -o [archive]" generates "extracting: file" output, instead of "inflating: file" output (which is written when I create the zip with the standard packing tool of mac). And so the automation tool can't find the uzipped .apk (i know, it is stupid, but lets take it as a constraint).

Related [infalting vs extracting](https://superuser.com/questions/211291/zip-file-decompression-inflating-vs-extracting)

Comment: The questions is why they bother how the .apk is packaged into the zip file. Furthermore the decision which compression is used is done automatically.

Comment: That is why I wrote: "i know, it is stupid, but lets take it as a constraint" (this should be handled by the automation tool, but on the other hand this should be configurable in the maven plugin as well). The automation tool tries to extract the name of the apk from the output of the standard mac unzip tool. It uses regexp to match to the line "inflating: [whatever].apk". And so it doesn't match to the "extracting: [whatever].apk".

Comment: If you really doing it with a correct regex it should handle both cases ` inflating: XXX.apk` or ` extracting: xxx.apk`. Unfortunately i don't see any possibility to influence the automatic compression detection of the underlying compression lib nor does an option etc. exist to change that behaviour. Apart from that i could argue that you should change the unzip tool to print out something different which fit the regex you use.

Comment: Unfortunately the whole automation tool is a "boxed" product. I can look into it, but I can't modify. So I can change the neither the unzip tool nor the regexp. :-(
But at least I've raised the issue to the developers of the automation tool.